# Creating a couchdb standalone attachment using cURL

Tags: database, linux, curl, couchdb, attachment

I am currently playing with couchdb and testing out the 'standalone attachments' feature, which is described near the bottom of [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API).

I am trying to use curl's   --data-urlencode feature to send the creation request, which only half works.   I can create the attachment and retrieve it, but the Content-Type field is wrong, so the image won't display correctly.

To be more accurate CouchDB seems to work by returning the attachment using the same Content-Type it was posted in. (which is perfectly sensible IMO) My problem is curl doesn't send the correct code.  Here's the details;

```
 curl -vX PUT http://localhost:5984/dafttest/666/attachment --data-urlencode image/jpeg@xi_on_beach.jpg
* About to connect() to localhost port 5984 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
> PUT /dafttest/666/attachment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.4 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost:5984
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 495389
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
```

So the short version of this question is; how to I get cURL to send the correct Content-Type ?

EDIT:

I release that my other mistake was to use --data-urlencode,  when to get it to work I need to use --data binary @filename together with the -H option that Dale suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [add headers with the -H/--header switch](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), so to add a header for image/jpeg content type, add this to your command:

> -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg"

Comment: I also needed --data-binary @filename  not --data-urlencoded, I've edited my post in case anyone else runs into this.